# Angular JS Controller Function Not Firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making a simple angular js app, but the controller function 'GetListings()' is not firing.

```
<body ng-controller="pageController">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Find Locations</h1>
        <p>Category:<br/><select id="category" name="category">
                            <option value="associate">associate</option>
                            <option value="contractor">contractor</option>
                            <option value="either" selected="selected">either</option>
                        </select></p>
        <p>Enter zip code:<br/><input type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" size="20"></p>
        <p>Enter radius (mi):<br/><input type="text" id="radius" name="radius" size="20"></p>
        <p><input type="button" id="lookup" value="lookup locations" ng-click="GetListings()"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="mainArea">
            <div class="directoryEntry" ng-repeat="listing in listings">
                <h4>{{listing.name}}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the angular code I am using:

```
function pageController ($scope) {

    $scope.listings =  [ {name : 'a' }, { name : 'b' }, { name : 'c' }, {name : 'd'}];

    $scope.GetListings = function () {

       console.log($scope.listings);

       $scope.listings.push( {name: 'e' } );

    }

}
```

The listings.name properties render correctly (a, b, c, d).  But 'e' does not get added.

Comment: How do you check if {name: 'e' } was added?

Comment: It should show up in the ng-repeat right? It should show up on the page.  Given the first console.log doesn't fire, I doubt it is getting into the GetListings function

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. Check http://plnkr.co/uvzYsoshZIML9RV5tCvY.

Comment: I had a subdirectory so it must have been going back to root.

Comment: it is working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/wy2Tv/

Answer (score 1):

Change line as below

```
<body ng-controller="pageController" ng-app>
```

at least required to ng-app in angularjs

Comment: I have <html ng-app> already.  That is working because it shows the first four listings

Comment: If you add ng-app in html tag so it must be work. And it is work for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, `GetListings()` is called when you click on "lookup locations" button.

According to your comment,

> It should show up in the ng-repeat right? It should show up on the page. Given the first console.log doesn't fire, I doubt it is getting into the GetListings function

Assuming you want to call `GetListings()` in the beginning, I have forked this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5W3q/1) where 'e' is listed in the beginning. You just need to call the function in controller once to push 'e' in the listings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code...

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alansouzati/eNLz8/) project with a div instead of body and everything works as expected. Which version of Angular you are using?

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="pageController">
      ....
  </div>
</div>
```